# Extension method with Interfaces

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have below interface

```
 public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void MethodB();
    }
```

I have below extension class:

```
public static class Extension
    {
        public static void MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension.MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, int i)");
        }

        public static void MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension.MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s)");
        }


        public static void MethodB(this IMyInterface myInterface)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension.MethodB(this IMyInterface myInterface)");
        }
    }
```

I have below class:

```
class B : IMyInterface
    {
        public void MethodB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B.MethodB()");
        }

        public void MethodA(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B.MethodA(int i)");
        }
    }
```

In my program, i have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.MethodA(7);
        b.MethodB();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

// Output strings in console of above program
```

B.MethodB() &
 B.MethodA(int i)

My Question: From MSDN, I understand that *An extension method will never be called if it has the same signature as a method defined in the type*

Why is MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s) is not shown up when i press b. in my program ?  As class B is missing a method with signature MethodA(string s) ,  MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s) should show up right ? But it doesn't.

Comment: What namespaces are you using?

Comment: It shows up for me... when I select `MethodA`, I get two options presented - one taking an `int` and one taking a `string`. Leaving intellisense aside, if you write `b.MethodA("foo");` does it compile and run?

Comment: Have you defined the extensions in the same namespace? If not you have to add the namespace with the using keyword.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel like a n00b now. Everything is working as it is supposed to work. I have started using resharper recently and the UI is bit different and hence i didn't observe the overload.

Can you post it as Answer so that i can mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 2):

It shows up. As "Class B" have the method with same name, so the method  "MethodA(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s)" will be presented as an overload of "MethdodA()". 
See below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have u referenced your extension class (using 'namespace of your extension class')? You need to add this directive where ever you want to use your extensions.